# How do I call a trait method on one of two Results when the trait is not object safe?

Tags: rust

I want a variable `model` to either be a `Model1` or a `Model2`, dependent on the actual model that is encoded in `bytes`. How do I merge the two model `Result`s, from which only one is `Ok()`?

```
let model1 = Model1::from_reader(&mut reader, &bytes);
let model2 = Model2::from_reader(&mut reader, &bytes);
let model = /* ??? */;
write_file(model).unwrap();
```

They both implement `MessageWrite`, which is the only trait that I need from this point on. Here is the prototype for `write_file()`

```
fn write_file<M: MessageWrite>(msg: M) -> io::Result<()>
```

I am using the quick-protobuf crate for the models. The `from_reader` prototype:

```
impl<'a> MessageRead<'a> for Model1<'a> {
    fn from_reader(r: &mut BytesReader, bytes: &'a [u8]) -> Result<Self> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And the `MessageWrite` trait. Note that is has a `Sized` bound.

```
pub trait MessageWrite: Sized {
     // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question and hope it is clearer now

Comment: Yes, much better. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pattern-matching. See this example:

```
trait MessageWrite: Sized {}

struct Foo;
struct Bar;

impl MessageWrite for Foo {}
impl MessageWrite for Bar {}

fn main() {
    let f: Result<Foo, ()> = Ok(Foo{});
    let b: Result<Bar, ()> = Err(());

    match (f, b) {
        (Ok(f), _) => write_file(f),
        (_, Ok(b)) => write_file(b),
        _ => panic!(),
    };
}

fn write_file<M: MessageWrite>(msg: M) -> std::io::Result<()> { Ok(()) }
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! The only problem left is that MessageWrite has a `Sized` bound, thus cannot be made into a object with `Box::new()`. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: @JuNijland Then you can call directly `write_file`